ssd cannot detected in dell poweredge server while installing ubuntu server 22.04, "Block probing did not discover any disks"
I try to install ubuntu server to my dell PowerEdge R650xs model server. In the installation, there is given an error which is about not seen disk to install in the system but I insert ssd to the server correctly and I can see it in bios. I did the things that discussed in this post Ubuntu Server 20.04 setup stuck at "Block probing did not discover any disks" but when I pass this stage it will again dont detect the ssd but just the usb pluged in the system for ubuntu server installation. I just stuck here.
SSD is samsung evo 870 and brand new. system model name: PowerEdge R650xs system bios version: 1.9.2
I also change RAID mode to AHCI mode from SATA Settings in bios and use it in uefi.
I change raid to ahci in sata settings but in system setup, it is seen Raid anyway in Device Settings. Why this is still in raid mode?
Where is the problem you think and how to handle this situation and install ubuntu server in this case?
Thanks.

it was because virtaul disk was not created. whatever you use, raid or ahci, you have to create virtual disk in bios after that, it will be seen.
